# Email Templates new symbol occurence

Tags: email, templates, special-characters, symbols, skype

we have a new email template triggering through emails.There is some special symbol that is : "Â" appearing prefixed to copyrights symbol.It is mentioned as below:
"©" all rights reserved.I have tried to sort out using all the possible ways like adding "­" or adding ascii symbols, encoding and decoding.but it seems to be not working.
 Also,skype symbol is not disanling in chrome even after adding metatag.adding "­" to it is displaying a special charecter as above...pls give me solution..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Â character is usually a sign to bad UTF-8 encoding handling:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8

But because your question is so vague, hard to read (bad in grammar) and lacks details it is not possible to help you further.